# How do I make my buttons work more than once in jquery?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Im trying to make only one div visible while others are just blacked out, so far Ive tried it with addClass and removeClass but it didnt work, changing css with jquery seemed to work, but only for once, I can click the buttons on and off for once, they will do the job and then just become useless, any solutions?

HTML

```
<div class="tamsus"></div> 

<button class = "on">On</button>
<button class = "off">Off</button>
```

jquery

```
    $(".on").click(function(){
      $(".tamsus").css({ "background-color": "black", "position": "absolute", "color": "#fff", "height": "100vh", "width": "100%", "z-index": "88", "opacity": "0.8"});
  });

     $(".off").click(function(){
      $(".tamsus").css({"display": "none"})
     });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues:

1. You are not removing `display: none` after it is added.
2. The overlay is on top of your buttons due to very high `z-index`, so once it is shown you can't click the buttons since they are behind it.

```js
const $tamsus = $(".tamsus")
$(".on").click(function() {
  $tamsus.removeClass('hidden');
});
$(".off").click(function() {
  $tamsus.addClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
}

.tamsus {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 88;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
}

.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tamsus hidden"></div>
<button class="on">On</button>
<button class="off">Off</button>
```